# Random variables with known ratios

Tags: bayesian, anova, small-sample, frequentist, regularization

I have $n$ samples with $m$ random variables in each: $\{x_{i\alpha}|i=1..n, \alpha=1..m\}$. The variables are expected to obey known ratios (they are fractions of an unknown quantity), e.g. $x_{\alpha}/x_\beta = f_\alpha/f_\beta$, where $f_\alpha$ are known constants. Due to noise some of the variables are way off: I would like to discard them and replace by the numbers based on the measurements that I deem reliable. For now I apply ANOVA and t-tests to $x_\alpha/f_\alpha$, treating measurements for each $\alpha$ as a group.

1. What kind of test could I use when $n$ is small (there might be situations where $n=1$, however $m\geq 3$ always)?
2. What is the smoother procedure for penalizing the outliers? (I am interested in some weighting scheme rather than simply throwing them away.)

I am mainly interested in well studied/standard/canonical procedures (my background is in a quantitative field other than statistics). Both frequentist and Bayesian approaches are of interest.

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Does the letter $\alpha$ change its meaning within the post? Does it change meaning two times?

Comment: Latin indices refer to samples, Greek to variables.

Comment: What is the nature of this noise?  For instance, can it be modeled as the *addition* of *independent* and *identically distributed* random variables *of zero mean* to the $x_\alpha$?  Probably not--but what characteristics should we use in place of addition/independent/identically distributed/zero mean/$x_\alpha$?

Comment: It is a mixture noise from other sets of variables with similar properties. If $n>1$, the affected variable if off in all samples.

Comment: I'm sorry--the vagueness of that comment and the corrupted grammar at the end make it impossible to understand.  If you wish an adequate reply, you need to edit your post to provide this information about the noise, because different kinds of noise lead to very different kinds of answers.

Comment: I suppose one could design a parametric test based on a specific noise model. But my question is about basic statistical procedures. I was hoping to be sent to appropriate textbooks.


In my previous comment: "the affected variable is off in all samples". Watch out when criticizing other people's grammar in front of an international audience ;)